# Starting faces flow

Tags: jsf-2, jsf-2.2, faces-flow

My question for today is: is it possible to start the faces flow without using `h:commandButton` component? In my particular case I would like to use the `h:selectOneMenu` component to start the particular flow based on the value selected by the user.

Comment: What have you tried? Using Ajax support with a `selectOneMenu`, I don't see why it wouldn't be possible to start a flow like you do with `h:commandButton`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is yes, but with a bit of tweaking. To enter a flow, it is required to create a navigation outcome that equals the flows id. [UICommand](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UICommand.html) components (like h:commandButton and h:commandLink) can do that but [UIInput](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIInput.html) components can not (they lack the "action" attribute). However, navigation may be triggered programmatically e.g. by using a [ValueChangeListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/event/ValueChangeListener.html):

```
    <h:form>
        <h:selectOneMenu value="#{requestScope.selectedFlow}">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="--- Select a Flow ---" noSelectionOption="true" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Flow A" itemValue="flow-a" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Flow B" itemValue="flow-b" />
            <f:valueChangeListener type="example.NaviagtionTargetListener" />
            <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@all"/>
        </h:selectOneMenu>           
    </h:form>
```

The corresponding ValueChangeListener:

```
public class NaviagtionTargetListener implements ValueChangeListener {

    @Override
    public void processValueChange(ValueChangeEvent event) throws AbortProcessingException {
        String target = (String) event.getNewValue();
        ConfigurableNavigationHandler nh =  (ConfigurableNavigationHandler) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().getNavigationHandler();
        nh.performNavigation(target);
    }

}
```

I created an example on GitHub[1] and wrote a blogpost about the usage of FacesFlow[2]

[1] https://github.com/tasel/facesflow-example

[2] http://blog.oio.de/2014/02/12/a-comprehensive-example-of-jsf-faces-flow/

Comment: Damn it! Can't even upvote Your answer due to my poor reputation, but anyways thank you for the clear example.

Comment: You are welcome :) Though upvoting may require more rep, you can 'accept' the answer

Comment: Instead of "unsafe" casting of `NavigationHandler`, you can call `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().getNavigationHandler().handleNavigation(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), null, target)` that effectively does the same thing.